# Using gl3w and Win32 api, without glut

Tags: opengl, win32

I'm still a beginner, the example on skaslev's site require us to use glut as an interface to create a window.

For some reason, I'm required to create a window purely with Win32 api, but I am not sure of how to integrate it together with gl3w.c

Is there a guide or tutorial on how to do that? I've been searching for hours, seems out of luck :(

Answer (score 1):

https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Creating_an_OpenGL_Context_(WGL)

After some research, this is where I learnt how to use gl3w without glut.